# What is the difference between formal language, regular language and regular expression?

Tags: formal-languages, terminology, regular-languages

I want to know the difference between these three languages and it would be great if you would give some examples as well.

Comment: What research did you do before asking here? This is all covered by any textbook or set of lecture notes, and there are many of them. For example, a regular language is some kind of set of strings, whereas a regular expression is a description of a set of strings. There's little point in writing out this stuff again when it's already available in so many places. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: i searched wikipedia for the definitions and for formal language there was written that it
"In mathematics, computer science, and linguistics, a formal language is a set of strings of symbols that may be constrained by rules that are specific to it."
and i think a regular language is also created by following some rules (regular expression) so i wanted to know what is the difference between theses two

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An *alphabet* $\Sigma$ is a finite collection of symbols. For example, $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$.

A *word* over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is a finite sequence of letters from $\Sigma$. For example, $0$, $01$ and $1110$ are all words over $\{0,1\}$. The empty word (that is, the empty sequence) is also allowed, and denoted $\epsilon$ (or sometimes $\lambda$).

The collection of all words over $\Sigma$ is denoted $\Sigma^*$.

A *formal language* over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is a set of words over $\Sigma$. Equivalently, a formal language over $\Sigma$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*$.

A *regular language* over $\Sigma$ is a formal language over $\Sigma$ which is accepted by some DFA.

A *regular expression* over $\Sigma$ has the following syntax:

1. $\epsilon$ is a regular expression.
2. $\sigma$ is a regular expression for all $\sigma \in \Sigma$.
3. If $r_1,r_2$ are regular expressions then so are $(r_1)^*$, $(r_1+r_2)$ and $(r_1r_2)$.

In practice we don't write all the parentheses. Each regular expression denotes some formal language (you will learn this translation in class). It turns out that a formal language is regular if and only if there is some regular expression denoting it.

If you have any more questions, I recommend reading a textbook which covers regular languages, for example [Hopcroft and Ullman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Automata_Theory,_Languages,_and_Computation).

Comment: _A regular language over ΣΣ is a formal language over ΣΣ which is accepted by some DFA._ - or can be described using regural expression and regural grammar, correct?

Comment: Yes, there are many equivalent definitions.

Comment: thanks, just wanted to make sure I understand [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45755/difference-between-regular-expression-and-grammar-in-automata/45756#45756) correctly